# Is there a way to connect Eclipse with Jira and Mercurial - or... would Code Beamer work?

Tags: eclipse, mercurial, jira

I am trying to research source control (mercurial) + issue trackers + ide all-in-one type of solution for my development team (6 people).
I would like to work in Eclipse. There is a mercurial plugin. There is a Jira plugin (I started using Jira and it is good for us, but if there is another solution, I'm open to here).
There is also a mercurial plugin for Jira!

But.... can you get all three to work together in Eclipse? So that you see a bug in your task list, then make some changes and commit, and your commit is linked to your jira bug...
Does anyone have experience with setting this up?

Thanks!!

p.s. this may be similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189601/eclipse-as-ide-mercurial-for-version-control-bug-tracking-good-idea), but since that is from 2008, I figured it's worth it to see if there is updated info

UPDATE: I saw a link on the MercurialEclipse plugin page for [Code Beamer Eclipse Studio](http://javaforge.com/project/CBES) - to connect to Code Beamer. This integrates with mercurial, so would provide the all-in-one functionality I want. But.... I went to the Code Beamer website and I can't figure out what it does, or if it would work for us. We need a system to creat issues/bug/feature requests, and then be able to move them through a workflow - open, assigned, in-progress, in-testing, ready for upload, test-on-production, completed. something like that. Would Code Beamer do the job?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is called Mylyn and by default part of Eclipse. Open the Team Synchronizing perspective, there you can find a Task Repositories view where you can create new repositories. Mylyn has plugins for all major issue trackers and source control systems. Here is a tutorial:

http://www.vogella.de/articles/Mylyn/article.html